# UIButton image/title inset alignment issues

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm having some troubles getting the contents of my button to be aligned correctly.  I set the insets to align the button to how I want it in the interface builder like this:

[image]

but then when I run the app in simulator it looks like this:

[image]

this button is using autolayout for sizing and alignment so I suspect that plays a role, but I can't figure it out.  I also tried to alter the insets programmatically inside of viewDidLoad but that doesn't seem to help at all.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you include some details re: how you're constructing your button? Re the image, you probably want to configure the contentMode to ScaleAspectFit. You can do that from interface builder or programmatically.

Comment: the purple part is a background image of the button, the bullseye is the image part of the button and the text is the titlelabel part of the button.  I've tried to set the content mode of the image itself in code but that doesn't make a difference. I don't think you can edit the properties of the image itself in interface builder when its part of a button

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't find a solution to this exact issue but I found another approach that did fix my visual issues:

Instead of using constraints, I used the Stack View controls available since iOS 9 to get the placement/sizing I was looking for. Since I'm creating a button grid, I just used vertical and horizontal stacks nested to create the button grid.

After implementing the stack views, the image and text of the button line up correctly.